# Position of a column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to know the Column position in a table in MS-SQL.
Eg: if a table consists of 3 columns namely column1, column2 and column3.
I should write a query so that i can get the position of column3 as **3**

Comment: If you want to select the column3 before column1 then you can achieve that using SELECT statement.

Comment: In SQL, as much as possible, you should be ignorant of the "position" of columns - columns are referenced by *name*, not by position. What *problem* are you trying to solve such that finding the position of the column appears to you to be part of the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'YourTableName' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'YourColumnName'
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get all these from information_schema.

```
select ordinal_position from information_schema.columns 
where schema_name = 'databasename'
and table_name = 'tablename'
and column_name = 'column name'
```

Comment: you have to include schema_name in your query, there're could be two tables with name 'tablename' in different schemas

Answer (score 1):

There're two ways to do this:

```
select colid
from sys.syscolumns
where id = object_id('schemaname.tablename') and name = 'column3'
```

and

```
select ordinal_position
from information_schema.columns 
where
    schema_name = 'schemaname' and
    table_name = 'tablename' and
    column_name = 'column3'
```

Here's an article about why you have to avoid information_schema views - [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views), I don't have to write this types of query often, so I don't really care about it, but sys.syscolumns tends to be a bit faster because it doesn't have many redundant joins which you may not need.

OTOH, information_schema views are ISO standard - here's dicussion about this - [SQL Server: should I use information_schema tables over sys tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653637/sql-server-should-i-use-information-schema-tables-over-sys-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Try the query and check for the result.

> select column_name,ordinal_position 
>       from information_schema.columns
>       where table_catalog = 'yourdatabasename'
>       and table_schema = 'yourschemaname'
>       and table_name = 'yourtablename'