# There are no my tables in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get information about amount of columns and types of these columns in certain table. I hear something about INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. But there are no my tables in it! What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: You are querying the `master` database. You need to switch context to your own database

Comment: As an aside, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA isn't all it's cracked up to be](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3654313/4137916).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `master` database.
Choose your database by `USE`

```
USE [YourDAtaBaseName]
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you a lot!