# How to dynamically calculate the sums of many columns in a GROUP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, aggregate-functions

In the table below, I have a variable number of columns, and that number is in the 1000s.  I need to sum all the values of each of the 1000 columns grouped by the person's name.  So, `smith's` total `test_score_1`, total `test_score_2`,...total `test_score_1000`.  And then `Jackson's` total `test_score_1`, total `test_score_2`,...total `test_score_1000`.

I don't know the number of '`test_score_n`' columns beforehand and they are always changing.

So given this table:

```
name      test_score_1 test_score_2 ...  test_score_1000
  smith        2              1                 0
  jackson      0              3                 1
  jackson      1              1                 2
  jackson      3              0                 3
  smith        4              5                 1
```

How can I produce the table below?

```
name      test_score_1 test_score_2 ...  test_score_1000
  smith        6              6                1
  jackson      4              4                6
```

Comment: You have 1000 columns?! First task: fix that madness immediately.

Comment: With biological data it is easy to have more than 1024 columns. One could argue that turning data wide should not be done in database management system but working with larger than ram data in R is painful mainly because the algorithms I need do not learn partially in chunks. I prefer to generate the dataset in sqlserver and use R or python for the data science part.

Comment: I'm still not convinced - I would still normalise the data into multiple table. Also, I would argue that if you still absolutely need 1000 columns, that a SQL database is probably not a good place to store the data.

Answer (score 7):

SQL to generate the SQL

```
DECLARE @generatedSQL nvarchar(max);

SET @generatedSQL = (

SELECT
    'SELECT ' + 
    SUBSTRING(X.foo, 2, 2000) + 
    'FROM ' + 
    QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) +
    ' GROUP BY name' --fix this line , edited
FROM
    sys.tables t
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
    SELECT
        ', SUM(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ')'
    FROM 
        sys.columns c 
    WHERE 
        c.object_id = t.object_id
        AND
        c.name <> 'Name'
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ) X (foo)
WHERE
    t.name = 'MyTable'
 );

EXEC (@generatedSQL);
```

Comment: Hi what does select 'select' mean? Could I add a group by clause to this code? I want to group by name (please see amendmended question) and then sum up the 1000 columns for each name. Thanks!

Comment: @gbn - I think you need to exclude `name` column from your `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: @user798719 - I suggest you check Google for "what is dynamic SQL"

Comment: @Alex why do you say that? I need it to generate the CSV

Comment: @user798719 The SQL needs generated because you decided to have 1000 columns. So I generate it.

Comment: @gbn I think what Alex means is `AND c.name <> 'name'` in the `WHERE` clause so the `name` column isn't included in the sums. Very minor further update - brackets are needed around the identifier in the last line, i.e. `EXEC (@generatedSQL)`.

Comment: @SteveChambers thanks, got it., The group by was added afterwards

Answer (score 4):

**Demo:** http://rextester.com/MAFCP19297

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @cols varchar(max), @sql varchar(max);

SELECT @cols = 
     COALESCE(@cols + ', ', '') + 'SUM(' + COLUMN_NAME + ') AS ' + COLUMN_NAME
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE table_name = '<tbl name>'
       AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'name'
       -- The AND below may be optional - see "Additional Notes #1"
       AND TABLE_CATALOG = '<database schema name>';

SET @sql = 'SELECT name, ' + @cols + ' FROM tbl GROUP BY name;';

EXEC (@sql);
```

**Explanation**

1. The `DECLARE` creates two variables - one for storing the column summing part of the SQL and the other for storing the whole dynamically created SQL statement to run.
2. The `SELECT` queries the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` system table to get the names of all the columns in `tbl` apart from the `name` column. *(Alternatively the sys tables could be used - answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653637) discuss the relative merits of each)*. These row values are then converted into a single comma separated value using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852#194887) *(which is arguably a little simpler than the alternative `FOR XML PATH ('')` method)*. The comma-separated values are a bit more than just the column names - they `SUM` over each column name and then assign the result with an alias of the same name.
3. The `SET` then builds a simple SQL statement that selects the name and all the summed values - e.g: `SELECT name, SUM(test_score_1) AS test_score_1, SUM(test_score_2) AS test_score_2, SUM(test_score_1000) AS test_score_1000 FROM tbl GROUP BY name;`.
4. The `EXEC` then runs the above query.

**Additional Notes**

1. If there is a possibility that the table name may not be unique across all databases then the following clause is needed in the select: `AND TABLE_CATALOG = '<database schema name>`'
2. My initial answer to this question was mistakenly using MySQL rather than SQL Server - this has now been corrected but the previous version is still in the edit history and might be helpful to someone...

Comment: Thanks alot for your explanation, helped alot.  And even a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Change `tablename` with your tablename.

```
     Declare @query as nvarchar(MAX) = (SELECT
    'SELECT name,' + SUBSTRING(tbl.col, 2, 2000) + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + 'Group By name'
FROM
    sys.tables t
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
    SELECT
        ', SUM(' + QUOTENAME(columns.name) + ') as ' + columns.name
    FROM 
        sys.columns columns 
    WHERE 
        columns.object_id = t.object_id and columns.name != 'name'
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ) tbl (col)
WHERE
    t.name = 'tablename')
select @query EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: this answer seems very inspired by the answer from @gbn

Comment: SELECT
            ', SUM(' + QUOTENAME(columns.name) + ') as ' + columns.name   I am having trouble understanding the code. How do you insert a "sum" to each column as opposed to summing all the columns once?  Where would I add a group by clause？ I want to group by "name" before I sum each of the 10000 dynamic columns.

Comment: I have an error using your code: "SELECT id, SUM([003]) as 003, SUM([008]) as 008, SUM([009]) as 009, SUM([010]) as 010, SUM([011]) ... SUM( FROM [dbo].[t1]Group By name"

Comment: I used a small sample that has 362 columns (003, 008, 009, etc are the column names).  the generated select statement doesn't show all columns, cutting off many.

Comment: @user798719 Please send full query and error detail. Same working in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this dynamic column generation Sql script

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max)

SET @Sql=( SELECT DISTINCT 'SELECT'+ 
                    STUFF((SELECT ', '+  ' SUM( '+ COLUMN_NAME +' ) AS '+ QUOTENAME( COLUMN_NAME )
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where TABLE_NAME ='Tab1000' 
                    FOR XML PATH (''),type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,'')
                    +' From Tab1000'From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where TABLE_NAME ='Tab1000')

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: I get this error: "Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator."  Any ideas?

Comment: what is the data type of columns in your table

Comment: The updated question has a more concrete example. The "test_score" column contents are all INT types. I would like to group by name and then SUM each of the 1000 "test_score" columns by the person' last name. I can do this if I hard code 1000 columns. I just don't know how to do the dynamic sql equivalent.

Comment: @Srini131 - you need to exclude `name` column e.g. `Where TABLE_NAME ='Tab1000'  AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Name'`

Answer (score 1):

Try the below script

**(set the @tableName= [yourTablename]  and @nameColumn to the name of the field you want to group by)**

```
    Declare @tableName varchar(50)='totalscores'
    Declare @nameColumn nvarchar(50)='name'

    Declare @query as nvarchar(MAX) ;

    select @query = 'select ' + nameColumn  + cast(sumColumns as nvarchar(max))  + 'from ' + @tableName +' group by ' + nameColumn     from (
    select @nameColumn nameColumn, (SELECT 
            ', SUM(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') ' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
        FROM
            sys.columns c
        WHERE
            c.object_id=t.object_id and c.name != @nameColumn
        order by c.name
        FOR 
            XML path(''), type
     ) sumColumns
     from sys.tables t where  t.name= @tableName
    )t

    EXECUTE(@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

**GBN's dynamic SQL would be my first choice (+1)**, and would be more performant.  **However**, if you are interested in breaking this horrible cycle of a 1,000+ columns, consider the following:

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([col 1] int,[col 2] int,[col 1000] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (2,1,0)
,(4,5,1)

Select Item  = replace(C.Item,'_x0020_', ' ')
      ,Value = sum(C.Value)
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData= cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml)) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item   = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value  = a.value('.','int') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Fields','ToExclude')
             ) C
 Group By C.Item
```

**Returns**

```
Item        Value
col 1       6
col 2       6
col 1000    1
```